# What does the minimum of a random variable mean?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, independence

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, \cdots,X_n$ be independent and identically distributred (iid) random variables. Then, how would you know/calculate what $min(X_1, X_2, X_3, \cdots,X_n)$ is?

Comment: How would you know or calculate the minimum of $n$ real numbers?  The process is no different.  See, for instance, [my discussion of sums of random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/392506/919) and just substitute "min" for "sum."

Comment: @whuber I was wondering since random variables don't have explicit variables and have random values. If a random variable would be smaller than another, would that mean all of its possible random values are less than the smallest possible value for the other random variable?

Comment: You need to study what a [random variable is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a way you are quite right: You cannot calculate \$min{X_1,X_2}$. Consider first the definition of a stochastic variable

**Definition:** A stochastic variable is a measurable ***function*** defined on a probability space whose outcomes are typically real numbers ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable)).

OK, so that means $X_1$ and $X_2$ are functions ...

But does that then mean you are supposed to read "$\min\{X_1,X_2\}$" as a question about which of the functions are smaller than the other? This seems problematic because obviously most functions do not take on only a single value. As you point out in your comment

*"would that mean all of its possible random values are less than the smallest possible value for the other random variable?"* ...

You have the same challenge for the expression "$min\{x^2,y^2\}$". Are you supposed to compare the function $x^2$ to see if it is smaller or larger than the function $y^2$?

In both context the answer is NO. You are supposed to read $g(x,y)=min\{x^2,y^2\}$, not as a comparison between two functions but as a definition of a function $g(x,y)$ that for a given $x$ and $y$ compares the values $x^2$ and $y^2$ and returns the smallest of the two values.

What then happens when you insert random variables in the function? Well **a function of random variables is itself a random variable**. So $\min\{X_1,X_2\}$ is a definition of a random variable - we could write $Y = \min\{X_1,X_2\}$ and you are not supposed to calculate its value instead it takes random values as function of $X_1$ and $X_2$. And as soon as you know the realizations of $X_1$ and $X_2$ calculation is trivial, for example let $X_1 =1$ and $X_2=2$ then $Y=1$.

There is a somewhat related confusion displayed in this question [conditional expectation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440589/expected-value-of-a-conditional-y-given-x-eyx-is-or-is-not-a-constant). An expectation $\mathbb E[Z]$ is simply a constant $\mu$. The conditional expectation $\mathbb E[Z\lvert W=w]$ returns a constant for a given $w$ hence it is a function $g(w) = \mathbb E[Z\lvert W=w]$. And finally $g(W)$ is a random variable
$\mathbb E[Z\lvert W]$ with the randomness originating from $W$. The point here is simply that remembering the definition of a stochastic variable and the fact that a function of stochastic variables is a stochastic variable is helpful (which shouldn't be a surprise).

Comment: Brilliant, once again!

Answer (score 1):

I think the first order statistic probably the answer you want.

you can get the distribution function of $r$-th order statistic by this equation:
$$
F_{X_(r)}(x) = \sum^n_{j=r} \binom{n}{j}[F_X(x)]^j[1-F_X(x)]^{n-j}
$$ and r = 1 is the minimun of these random variables.

If you need more (like margin pdf), you can check on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic). There is some cases of specified distribution.

Comment: The question asks about how to define a function of a sequence of random variables.  It does not ask about distributions.

Comment: Yes, this is where my question originated from.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment than an answer but as a newbie I can't comment yet.

What do you mean by calculate?

- If you mean retrieve the distribution, then without knowing the original distribution this will be hard.
- If by calculate you mean in practice what does it mean, then it just means that you repeat your experiment $n$ times in order to get n values, you then take the minimum of those values. If you repeat this process a significant amount of time you will be able to plot the distribution of your new random variable.

To illustrate with an example, if n is large and X is evenly distributed on a finite interval [a,b], here your new r.v. will also be defined on [a,b] but the probability to get values around $a$ will be super high.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the "calculate" part. The accepted answer makes me realize they are functions and so the answer wouldn't just be some random variable from $X_1, X_2, X_3, \cdots, X_n$.