# Prove $P(A\cap B)>P(A)P(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent conditional on $C$ and $P(A|C)>P(A|C')$ and $P(B|C)>P(B|C')$

Tags: probability, covariance, independence, indicator-function

I want to prove that $P(A\cap B)>P(A)P(B)$ given:

1. $P(A\cap B|C)=P(A|C)P(B|C)$
2. $P(A\cap B|C')=P(A|C')P(B|C')$
3. $P(A|C)>P(A|C')$
4. $P(B|C)>P(B|C')$
5. $P(C)\neq 0,1$

Where $C'$ is the compliment of $C$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [law of total covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance) applied to indicator variables for the different events it follows that
\begin{align}
P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B) 
   &= E(I_{A \cap B})-E(I_A)E(I_B)
\\ &= E(I_A I_B)-E(I_A)E(I_B)
\\ &= \operatorname{Cov}(I_A,I_B)
\\&= E \operatorname{Cov}(I_A,I_B|I_C)+\operatorname{Cov}(E(I_A|I_C),E(I_B|I_C)).
\end{align}
The first term in the final expression is zero because of conditional independence (1. and 2.).  The second term is positive because of 3. and 4. which creates a positive association between the two conditional expectations.

An analogous treatment of the amount of [linkage disequilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_disequilibrium) generated by mixing genetically differentiated populations can be found in Joe Felsenstein's [population genetics textbook](http://evolution.gs.washington.edu/pgbook/pgbook.pdf), pp. 177-178.

Comment: I don't understand your second point, would it be possible for you to explain how 3. and 4. create a positive association between the two conditional expectations ?

Comment: @CamilleGontier The conditional expectations, being functions of the indicator $I_C$, are themselves random variables with a joint bivariate discrete distribution.  They take the values $P(A|C),P(B|C)$ with probability $P(C)$ and the values $P(A|C'),P(B|C')$ with probability $P(C')$.  So given 3. and 4. they clearly have positive covariance.

Comment: @CamilleGontier Also, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/440597/77222