# The distribution function of the min of two random variables which are dependent via a common term

Tags: probability, expected-value, moment-generating-function

Consider the following two random variables:

$$Z_1=U_1-X_1$$
and
$$Z_2=U_2-X_1,$$
where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are two i.i.d random variables following a general distribution, and $X_1$ is an exponential random variable. It is obvious that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are two dependent random variables. Now, let us consider the following random variable:
$$Y=\min(Z_1,Z_2).$$
Is there any explicit expression or approximation for the PDF or expected value of $Y$?

Comment: Note that $\min(x,y) = \frac{x+y - \lvert x - y\rvert}{2}$...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The distribution of $Y$ can also be written as $$Y = \min(Z_1,Z_2) = \min(U_1,U_2) - X_1 = Q-X_1$$

This contains two parts:

- The distribution of a minimum of iid variables $Q=\min(U_1,U_2)$ whose cdf can be expressed in terms of the cdf of $U_i$, $$P(\min(U_1,U_2)> x) = P(U_i > x)^2$$
- The distribution of a sum $Q-X_1$, [which can be found with a convolution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331973/why-is-the-sum-of-two-random-variables-a-convolution/331983#331983).

Answer (score 6):

As noted by @YashaswiMohanty the expectation of $Y$ can sometimes
be found without explicting the probability distribution function.

Assume that all r.vs are of continuous type and $X_1$ is exponential
with rate $\lambda >0$. We can consider the survival function
$\bar{F}_Y(y) := 1 - F_Y(y)$

$$
\bar{F}_Y(y) = \text{Pr}\{ \min(Z_1,\,Z_2) > y\}
=\text{Pr}\{[Z_1 > y] \cap [Z_2
> y] \}. 
$$
Then by conditioning on $X_1$ we can use the independence
\begin{align*}
\bar{F}_Y(y) 
&=\int_0^\infty \text{Pr}\{[Z_1 > y] \cap [Z_2
> y] \, \vert \, X_1 = x_1\} f_{X_1}(x_1) \,\text{d}x_1\\
&= \int_0^\infty \text{Pr}\{[U_1 > y + x_1] \cap [U_2
> y + x_1] \, \vert \, X_1 = x_1\} \, f_{X_1}(x_1) \,\text{d}x_1\\
&=  \int_0^\infty \bar{F}_U(y + x_1)^2 \lambda \, e^{-\lambda x_1}\, \text{d}x_1
\end{align*}

There are some cases where we can get a closed form expression. For
instance if $U_i$ are exponential with rate $\gamma$ i.e.,
$\bar{F}_U(u) = e^{-\gamma u}$ for $u >0$.

Interestingly, this is a simple and efficient way to generate a couple
of random variables with tail dependence.