Controversial view that Convolutions of a PDF might not be a PDF
There is this thread which says the convulution formula which integrates a $f(x) \cdot f(s-x)\,dx,$ again returns a PDF. I kinda agree with this. But then, I came across this youtube video. I am providing the links to them below.
At 00:15:30 in the video if the single curve on the right (triangle shaped) is a PDF, then what does he mean when he says, "this number $s$ is an input to that (convolution) function, and the corresponding output, is whatever the area of the lower left graph is".
I understand that, probability of $s$ taking an exact value should ideally be $0.$ Then how can he say that "the corresponding output, is whatever the area of the lower left graph is". As probability, ergo the area should limit to $0.$
Links:
Proving the Convolution of PDFs gives a PDF
https://youtu.be/IaSGqQa5O-M?si=smyv_63FsMNkH9ly&t=930

You can improve this post by making it independent from youtube. Without the video it is unclear what the question is.

Welcome to CV, Smit.  It's often productive to search this site for answers before you go to the effort of posting a question: we have been here for over 14 years and just about any question about the basics has been asked and answered.  Take a look at posts related to pdf convolution.  Make sure to look at some of the highest-voted posts, too.

Related is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/331973/ but you seem to be asking specifically about the meaning of the area.

I see two issues

and the corresponding output, is whatever the area of the lower left graph is

What is the meaning of that area?

probability of s taking an exact value should ideally be 0.

Why isn't the output zero?

Here is an on the back of an envelope explanation.

In the image above we see an example sketch with a joint normal distribution (the video that you refer to uses a uniform distribution, but the principle is the same).
You can imagine that total distribution as being composed out of slices where the sum $s=x+y$ is constant. In the image above we have cut the distribution along the slice where $s=x+y = -1$.
We can note two geometrical shapes.

The volume under the function $f(x,y)$ where $x+y > s$
That is the probability for the event $X+Y>s$ and related to the cumulative distribution function of the sum of $X$ and $Y$ $$P(X+Y>-1) = 1-F(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{s-x}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy \right) dx$$

The area under the function $f(x,y)$ where $x+y = s$.
You can see this as the density of the sum $X+Y$ or the relative size of the individual slizes at a particular value of the sum.
It is the derivative or rate of change of the volume when we change $s$ in the computation of the probability for the event $X+Y>s$
$$\begin{array}{}
f(s) &=& -\frac{\partial}{\partial s} P(X+Y>s)\\
& = & - \frac{\partial}{\partial s}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\int_{s-x}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy \right] dx\\
& = & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} -\frac{\partial}{\partial s}   \left[\int_{ s-x}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy \right] dx \\
&= &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f_{X,Y}(x,s-x)dx\\
&= &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  f_X(x)f_Y(s-x)dx
\end{array}$$


The volume (related to the probability) of these slizes is indeed zero when you consider slizes of zero thickness. But they do have a non-zero area, and that area relates to the volume of an infinitesimal thin slice $ds$.

Let's consider a simple example to recall what are some properties of a density function. consider the uniform distribution $\textrm{Uni}(0,1)$: in that case, we can write $$f(s)=\begin{cases} 1, s \in (0,1) \\ 0, s \notin (0,1)\end{cases}$$
While the probability of taking any particular value is $0$ for this continuous random variable, $f$ does take certain values. In this case, it takes values $1$ or $0$, but the probability at any particular value is $0$. To find the corresponding probability of a particular range, we integrate the density function.
Now, let's go back to the video.
$[f*g](s)$ is indeed a density function, $s$ is the corresponding input of the density function.  For the corresponding density value , we have  $$[f*g](s) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g(s-x)\, dx.$$
Recall that integral of a nonnegative function can be interpreted as the area under the graph; thus the density function of $X+Y$ is equal to the area under the graph of $f(x)g(s-x)$ where we integrate $x$ over the whole real line while holding $s$ fixed.
